# Unity - Loading assetbundle from usb storage on android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, usb, loading, assetbundle

I have a project in unity that requires very heavy textures, so I want to load them via usb.

I have already loaded assetbundles from local storage, but I want to know if I can load them from a usb drive without the files going into the device for temp storage (Because the files are very large).

Can I load assetbundles like that from a usb drive? Or alternatively can I put the textures on the usb load them?

Thanks!

Comment: So you will be giving everybody that will use your unity program a USB drive a long with the application? If not, you might just want to look into texture optimization.

Comment: Yes, thats what I'm planning to do.
It is an a project for clients, and each client will receive a USB drive.

Comment: Sounds a bit impractical to me, have you considered that asset bundles can be loaded from on-line sources such as a server?

Comment: Thank you for your answer by the way, and yes, thats what I'm currently doing, but the textures need to be very big (maybe even a few gigs for all of them), so not everyone will have space of their phones for them. I would like to have an option to bring a usb drive with the textures for very large projects, so that the clients wont have to store the textures on their devices.

Comment: If you have access to the USB drive, and you load them without using WWWs LoadFromCacheOrDownload, you should be fine.

Comment: as a curiosity, what do you mean by **large**?  a couple GB is nothing.  if it's Android, just put the app on yourServer.com/NiceClient/app.apk and people can click the link and load and play the app.  Nobody will even notice the size.

Comment: Thanks guys, the textures are per client, and they will maybe be a couple gigs, so I wanted them to be stored on a usb drive becuase I, for example only have 1 gig available on my phone.
Bart - Thatt is what I'm asking, how to access the usb drive from unity.
Thank you!